# Twilio account locked and zero support. Reset password email not sent and not in spam

Tags: twilio

So we've been locked out of our Twilio account.  The request password reset doesn't not send an email. Support won't answer any support tickets at all and we are stuck with major business conflicts over this.

Comment: Unfortunately, SO isn't the place to deal with this...

Comment: Did @philnash ever respond to your inquiry, @ryanwillb????

Comment: @Seth do you need help at all?

Comment: No, I found this article while I was wondering what caused a lock-out of our account earlier that day. Everything was resolved not too long after commenting here. Was wondering if you ever provided @ryanwillb with information regarding the reason for the lock-out (too many incorrect password attempts or something more concerning). Regarding the user experience, I think a helpful message would be useful, or maybe a password attempt counter for context. Otherwise, all is well in the cosmos. Thanks for responding though :D